# Sphinx saying: FATAL: no readable config file

Tags: ubuntu, full-text-search

```
root@ded69-145:/var/lib/mysql# /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart
Restarting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.0.4-id64-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

FATAL: no readable config file (looked in /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf, ./sphinx.conf).
```

I'm getting this error but the config file is definitely there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing `searchd` - this will fire up the indexes and start the Sphinx Daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Even though its saying the error what you mentioned(FATAL: no readable config file), i don't think it will not affect the usage of sphinx when you configured in your project. If you search the config file it might be with the name sphinx.conf.dist. You just start index the file and it will work fine. The same error throws for me but it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed the package using yum install sphinx, you have to start using service searchd start, and update config file in /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf, but if you want to use /etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart you have to specify config file with --config and the path where the config file is.